# Backbone routing keeping hashtags when navigate()

Tags: backbone.js

Hello here is my scenario.

I have these routes

```
    routes: {
    "": "show_group_list",
    "!/group/:_id/": "show_group",
},
```

and here is my navigate function:

```
                App.app.navigate('!/group/'+group.get('_id')+'/', { trigger: true });
```

when the function is triggered, on the address bar it shows **localhost/group/1** instead of *localhost/#!/group/1*. The problem is that when I refresh the page I don't get the initial page anymore (mine is a single page app)

How can I hack navigate() so that it keeps the hashtag?

Comment: You might want to remove any leading slashes as well as Backbone doesn't play well (see documentation) with leading slashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, This was easy, I had pushState enabled. Disable pushState and you'll have back the hash